# Two Layer Nested Serializers - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Say I have models with grandparent-parent-child relations like so:

**models.py**

```py
class Unit(...):
    number = models.CharField(...)

class Listing(...):
    unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit', related_name="listings", ...)
    number_of_bedrooms = models.IntegerField(...)

class Price(...):
    listing = models.ForeignKey('Listing', realted_name="prices", ...)
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)
```

Using DRF - how can I grab all of the `price` instances for a listing in the `ListingSerializer`; all `prices` are determined by the grandparent `Unit`.

I am trying:

**serializers.py**

```py
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ["amount"]

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prices = PriceSerializer(
        source="unit__listings__prices",    # <-- this does not seem to work
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
    )
    ...
```

Essentially:

- a unit can have multiple listings
- a listing can have multiple prices
- a unit will have many prices as its "grandchildren"
- how can I get all of the price "grandchildren" on the `ListingSerializer`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `serializers.SerializerMethodField`.

```py
# views.py
class ListingView(...):
   queryset = Listing.objects.prefetch_related("prices")
   ...


# serializers.py
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      prices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


      def get_prices(self, obj):
          # queryset for prices related to a listing instance: obj
          prices = obj.prices.all() 

          data = PriceSerializer(prices, many=True).data
          return data
    
    ...
```

Comment: To grab all of the price instances for a listing. You could do:
prices = Price.objects.filter(listing_id=obj.id)
Where obj is gotten from get_prices()

Comment: This is ok - but how can I leverage `prefetch_related` so that my list response doesn't have a lot of duplicate SQL queries?

Comment: I initially left that for your discretion, but I will update my answer to give you an idea on how to go about it